# To check given set is a bounded set?

Tags: real-analysis

The set $\{(x,y,z) \in R^3: x^8+y^4+z^8-16=0\}$ is a bounded set?
I guess it isn't a bounded set because from $x,y,z \geq 0$ i suppose it's only inferiorly bounded.
Is it correct? Please tell me the correct answer.

Comment: what have you tried?

Comment: Notice that each exponent in your set condition is even.

Comment: Since the figure is symmetric about xy,yz and zx plane we only have to show that the figure is bounded in the first octant where $x,y,z  \ge 0$. If the figure was unbounded then $\exists$ at least one coordinate which is increasing without any bound. Let's say the coordinate to be $x$. Then gradually $x^8+y^4+z^8 > 16$. Isn't it so?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Note that $x^8$, $y^4$ and $z^8$ are all nonnegative. What can you say about the quantity $x^8+y^4+z^8$ if $|x|>\sqrt{2}$, $|y|>2$ or $|z|>\sqrt{2}$?

Comment: I can say this: $x^8 \leq x^8+y^4+z^8=16$ and then $x^8 \leq 16$. Let's say that $-\sqrt{2} \leq x \leq \sqrt{2} $. The same for y and z.

Answer (score 0):

For this question, it really matters what you mean by bounded. You originally tagged your post as with topology, so I'll assume that's what you're interested in seeing.

In topology, we say that a set is bounded if it can be contained in a ball of finite size. You can formally show that this set is bounded by constructing a ball $B$ of radius $r > 0$, centered at some $x \in \mathbb{R}^3$, and showing that every point in the set is contained in the ball.

**Hint:** What is the formula for the surface of a sphere / ellipsoid?

Comment: This is the question:

Let $g:R^3\rightarrow R $ denote a function where $g(x,y,z)=x^8+y^4+z^8-16$ and let $A$ a subset of $R^3$ where $A=\{(x,y,z)\in R^3:g(x,y,z)=0\}$
Discuss which of the following assertions are true :

a) A is limited (or bounded it's the same i think)

b) A is closed (and this is correct!)

c) A is a surface (this is correct!)

d) A is a curve (it isn't correct)

e) Exist a point ($x_0,y_0,z_0) \in A$ such as $\nabla g(x_0,y_0,z_0)=(0,0,0)$ (this sentence isn't correct!)

Then the solution for a) is that A is limited?